# Cosmos DB Partition Query and RU Charges

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm using the Volcano JSON sample with 1571 documents.  I created one container (using the Cosmos DB Emulator) partitioned by ID and one container partitioned by Country.  I expected to see that when I ran these queries:

```sql
select *
from VolcanoesById c
where c.Country = 'Japan'


select *
from VolcanoesByCountry c
where c.Country = 'Japan'
```

The RU cost listed in the emulator has the same charge:

Partitioned by ID:

- Request Charge - 6.25 RUs
- Results - 111
- Retrieved document size - 56255 bytes
- Output document count - 111
- Output document size - 56416 bytes
- Index hit document count - 111
- Index lookup time - 0.13 ms
- Document load time - 0.5 ms
- Query engine execution time - 0.09 ms

Vs the partition by country:

- Request Charge - 6.25 RUs
- Results - 111
- Retrieved document size - 56255 bytes
- Output document count - 111
- Output document size - 56416 bytes
- Index hit document count - 111
- Index lookup time - 10.96 ms
- Document load time - 0.46 ms
- Query engine execution time - 0.11 ms

Shouldn't the query by country partitioned on country be a smaller RU result?

Answer (score 2):

The reason could be that the Container you created has a single [physical partition](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#physical-partitions).

Try creating in the Emulator containers with multiple physical partitions (you can achieve that by provisioning more than 10K RU) and repeating the same exercise.